# Sniffing function calling between application executable file and 3d party library

Tags: c, dll, mfc

I have an application which is written with MFC. The application uses a c library (there are .h, .dll and .lib files in the lib folder).

Can I sniff the function calling of .exe with the library? I want to know which function of the .h files are called.

More info: the library is D2XX and of course the source code of the application or the debug mode of the application is not available.

Comment: Write a proxy DLL, that intercepts all calls to the 3rd party library. Have it export the same symbols as the original DLL, and import those symbols from the original DLL to forward calls. Rename the proxy DLL to match the name of the original DLL.

Comment: On Solaris, you could use truss(1) for that, but I don't know of any equivalent software for Windows.

Comment: There should actually be no "functions in the `.h` file" called, as that should not include _definitions_ (`inline` functions are somewhat special).

Answer (score 2):

You could try out [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), which seems to support tracing of custom DLL library calls: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/37421-monitor-custom-dll/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that